# Updating a sum (Ex. spaces = spaces + 2) with for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

Okay, I'm making a program that'll make vertical lines, horizontal lines, diagonals lines too! I'm kinda confused on one of my outputs that doesn't make any sense.

So my psudocode was like this:

```
  //enter a char
  //enter a number that will determine how long the line is
  //define with easyreader what type of line it will be (hori, vert, diag)
  //the idea of making the diag lines was this...

  @
  (two spaces) @
  (four spaces) @
  (six spaces)   @

  //we could use the sum spaces = spaces + 2; to keep on calculating what 
  //the previous spaces was
```

Code was:

```
  class starter {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {   
        System.out.print("What char would you like? ");
        EasyReader sym = new EasyReader();
        String chars = sym.readWord();
        System.out.print("How long would you like it to be? ");
        int nums = sym.readInt();
        System.out.print("Diag, Vert, or Hori? ");
        //you want to read the __ varible, not the sym.readX()
        String line = sym.readWord();

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");

        if(line.equals("Hori")){
            for(int x = 0; x < nums; x++){
                System.out.print(chars + " ");  
            }
        }

        else if(line.equals("Vert")){
            for(int y = 0; y < nums; y++){
                System.out.println(chars + " ");
            }
        }

        else{
            for(int xy = 0; xy < nums; xy++){
                for(int spaces = 0; spaces < nums; spaces++){
                spaces = spaces + 2;
                System.out.print(spaces + " ");
                System.out.println(chars);
                }
            }
        }

    }
 }
```

At the bottom you will see a for loop called xy that will read how long the lines would be. Under that for loop would control the spaces. However, for some reason, the sum isn't updating correctly. The output is always:

```
 2 (char)
 5 (char)
 8 (char)
 2 (char)
 5 (char)
 8 (char)
 ...
```

The output should be:

```
 2 (char)
 4 (char)
 8 (char)
 ...
```

EDIT ********** 
Since I need help now changing incriements here is an example (So I don't have to explain it a lot in comments)

Example: If user puts he wants the line as much as 5 units. With two for loops, one controlling how many spaces he wants, one controlling how many chars will print out, the output would be then 2, 4, 6, 8, 10.

Comment: Your loop is calling `spaces++` every iteration.

Comment: `for(int spaces = 0; spaces < nums; spaces++){` and `spaces = spaces + 2;`  - you are updating the same variable in multiple places.

Comment: How can I fix the for loop so it won't keep on updating like this? Should I remove it or ...

Comment: I assume an expected output would be `2`, `4`, `6`.

Comment: Yeah. I need it that way so I can then assign them to spaces.

Comment: I mean rather than `2`, `4`, `8`. ;)

Comment: Example: if I had the line as long as 5 dots, I would need to calculate spaces  5 times. So the out put I would like would be then: 2, 4, 6, 8, 10. I changed the increment to be one now, but now its 1, 5, 8. I'm getting a better view of what for loops do now

Answer (score 3):

In `for` loop statement, you say 'increase `spaces` by one after each iteration' (`spaces++`):

```
for(int spaces = 0; spaces < nums; spaces++){
```

In the body of your loop, you additionally ask to increase it by 2:

```
spaces = spaces + 2;
```

So each iteration it gets increased by 3.

By the way, there seems to be something wrong with your nested loops (if I understand the intention correctly). If the outer loop (looping over `xy`) draws a line on each iteration, then the inner loop, which is supposed to output an indent for the current line, must be bounded by `xy` (multiplied by 2) rather than `nums`. I'd write it like this:

```
for (int xy = 0; xy < nums; xy++) {
    for (int spaces = 0; spaces < xy*2; spaces += 2) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(chars);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are adding 3 to the spaces each time

```
for(int spaces = 0; spaces < nums; spaces++){
    spaces = spaces + 2;
```

**spaces++**  spaces += 1

**spaces = spaces + 2;**   spaces += 2

Answer (score 0):

actually the problem is in this part :

```
for(int spaces = 0; spaces < nums; spaces++){
      spaces = spaces + 2;
      System.out.print(spaces + " ");
      System.out.println(chars);
}
```

when the program starts we have `spaces = 0`

then this part is going to run `spaces =spaces + 2`

now `spaces` is equal to `2`, so we have `spaces = 2`

the program prints `2`, after that `spaces` increments by `1` using `spaces++` part

now `spaces` is equal to `3`, which means `spaces=3`

after that this line is going to be run `spaces = spaces + 2`

so the value of `spaces` becomes `5`

and if we do this for ever and ever we will have this sequence of numbers :

`2   5   8   11   14   ....`

in fact this is because we are incrementing `spaces` by `3` in each iteration

if you modify your code in this form, the problem is going to be solved :

```
for (int xy = 0; xy < nums; xy++) {
    for(int spaces = 0; spaces < xy*2; spaces += 2)
          System.out.print(spaces + " ");
    System.out.println(chars);
}
```

Comment: @PYRO 912 you need to trace the code , i've done it for you in two steps